# Dedekind-MacNeille Completion

Tags: lattice-orders

Let $\mathbb{N}$ be the set of natural numbers.

a) Describe the Dedekind-MacNeille completion of the poset of finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$.

b) Describe the Dedekind-MacNeille completion of the poset of cofinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$.

c) Describe the Dedekind-MacNeille completion of the poset of finite and cofinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$.

Here is my efforts to do with part a.
Call $P$ is the poset of finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$.
Suppose $A$ is an element in the power set of $P$. Then $A^{u}$, which is the set of all upper bound of $A$. Then we have $A^u$ is the set of elements of the form $A \cup B$ where $B$ is an element in the power set of $P$. And then take $\left(A^u\right)^l = A^{ul}$, which is the set of all lower bounds of $A^u$, we have $A^{ul}$ contains the $\emptyset$ and all subsets of $A$.
Then by the definition of Dedekind-MacNeille, I conclude $A = \left\{\emptyset\right\}$ and $A = \left\{\emptyset, \left\{n\right\}\right\}$, where $n$ is a natural number.

Do I messed up something? And I still stuck with b and c. So any hint is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Obviously you messed up something. You picked $A$ an element of the powerset of $P$. Then you conclude that $A=\{\varnothing\}$ or $\{\varnothing,\{n\}\}$. This can't be right. Apparently, you got the right value for $A^u$, but from then on, nothing seems right. Remember that the Dedekind—MacNeille completion of a poset is the "least" complete lattice into which you can embed the poset. You know that, don't you? (You could be bound to use the definition.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to tackle this problem is to use the following result, which you can find, for example, in Davey and Priestley, *Introduction to Lattices and Order*.

> **7.41 Theorem.**
>   Let $P$ be a poset and let $\varphi:P\to\mathbf{DM}(P)$ be the order-embedding of $P$ into its Dedekind—MacNeille completion given by $\varphi(x) = \,\downarrow\!x$.
>    (i) $\varphi(P)$ is both join-dense and meet-dense in $\mathbf{DM}(P)$.
>   (ii) Let $\mathbf L$ be a complete lattice and assume that $P$ is a subset of $L$ which is both join-dense and meet-dense in $L$. Then $\mathbf L \cong \mathbf{DM}(P)$ via an order-isomorphism which agrees with $\varphi$ on $P$.

Now, let us see how we could use this result to answer (a) and (c).
(Notice that (b) is similar to (a), so I'll leave it to you.)

If $P$ is the poset of finite subsets of $\mathbb N$, then I claim that $P\cup\{\mathbb N\}$ is its Dedekind—MacNeille completion.
Let us use (ii) from the Theorem to show it.
To start with, you can easily show that $P\cup\{\mathbb N\}$, with the $\subseteq$ order relation, is a complete lattice.
Now, given an element of $P\cup\{\mathbb N\}$, we show that it is the join and the meet of some subset of $P$.
For the element $\mathbb N$, we have that $\mathbb N = \bigwedge \varnothing = \bigvee \{\{n\}:n \in \mathbb N\}$, so we're done; any other element $A$ belongs to $P$, so we just say $A = \bigwedge\{A\}=\bigvee\{A\}$.

In the case of (c), that is, $P$ is the poset of finite and co-finite subsets of $\mathbb N$, I claim that the Dedekind—MacNeille completion of the finite and co-finite subsets of $\mathbb N$ is the powerset of $\mathbb N$.
Indeed, any full powerset lattice is a complete lattice.
Now take $A \subseteq \mathbb N$. 
Then
$$A = \bigcup \{ \{a\} : a \in A \} = \bigcap \{ \mathbb N \setminus \{b\} : b \notin A \}.$$
Since $\{a\}$ is a finite subset of $\mathbb N$, for each $a \in A$ and $\mathbb N \setminus \{b\}$ is a co-finite one, for each $b \notin A$, we get that $P$ is both join-dense and meet-dense in the powerset of $\mathbb N$.